# Why is this jQuery code takes too much time to execute?

Tags: html, jquery, typescript

I have a very simple jquery code that makes a button to fade in:

```
function showOne() {
console.log("SHOW");
$('.closebt').fadeIn('slow');
}
```

this code is called by HTML:

```
<a (click)="showOne()">SHOW</a>
```

and this is the element:

```
<div class="closebt">
  <button type="button">Click Me!1</button>
  <button type="button">Click Me!12</button>
</div>
```

the `console.log("SHOW");` is executed immediately as seen in Chrome console, but the `$('.btn1').fadeIn('slow');` makes the button appear after 8-10 seconds, how can I make the buttons appear immediately?

Comment: does this still happen when you use ...fadeIn(1)? aka could your .fadeIn('slow') be set to a long time?

Comment: Works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/t3k5eL64/11/

Comment: Xgongiveittoya fadeIn(1) changes nothing. it looks like there is a general website delay, not something caused by 'slow' or delayed fadein effect. 
Bernard Borg it definitely works, there is no question about the code, but how to troubleshoot such issue? how to identify what cause the delay?

Comment: you maybe have javascript running in background and if you have to troubleshoot the issue I can't think of anything better than commenting every source of javascript code running keeping alive only jquery  and this fadein procedure. If it will work as expected start adding back everything you disabled piece by piece until things stop working again and you'll have the culprit. Put also an eye on the network tab in the browser developer tools to see in real time http requests ongoing because it could be a further clue of ajax requests in background.